# Npgsql Inserting earth data in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a PostgreSQL database with the earthdistance module activated. 
    I have a column with data type set to earth.
    Is there a way to insert a new record using Npgsql?
    I have tried to use the ll_to_earth(lat,long) function but receive the error
   "installation_location\" is of type earth but expression is of type text"

```
int din_id = 5;
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO installation_test 
                               (installation_id,  installation_location ) " +
                               "VALUES (@uin_id, @uin_loc  ) ", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uin_id", din_id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uin_loc", 
                                  "ll_to_earth(-23.482409,153.141043)");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Parameters can't be used in this way: you can't put arbitrary SQL in your parameter data, to be executed by the database (in your case, the `ll_to_earth` function call). The database doesn't evaluate parameter data as SQL, but expects an actual value. What you're looking for is probably a simple INSERT without any parameters:

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO installation_test 
                    (installation_id,  installation_location ) " +
                    "VALUES (@uin_id, ll_to_earth(-23.482409,153.141043)) ", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uin_id", din_id);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can, however, parameterize the points which you pass to `ll_to_earth`:

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO installation_test 
                    (installation_id,  installation_location ) " +
                    "VALUES (@uin_id, ll_to_earth(@x,@y)) ", connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uin_id", din_id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("x", -23.482409);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("y", -23.482409);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That's excellent thank you - I knew if i put the function in the VALUES  statement it worked but didn't realize the parameters could be added.